# kendowindow not closing in chain of functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I have a problem with kendowindow close function, It's not working in a code like this

```
function buttonclick(){   
 $("#Window1").data("kendoWindow").close(); 
 $("#loadingpopup").show(); 
 GetDatafromfunc1();
 }
```

It's close at the end of GetDatafromfunc1() execution.
how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

There was no changes like closing windows or showing popup happened to the page because GetDatafromfunc1() has an ajax call with `async=false` which was blocking the browser, so i removed it and do the chain of functions which depends on each other in the success part of each call.